# Difference between flash.now and @instance_var

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering what the difference is between using `flash.now` and simply using an instance variable (e.g. `@error_message`)?

On a related note, how does `flash` work when you have multiple servers running, and thus there's a probability that the subsequent request will be executed by a different server?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering what the difference is between using flash.now and simply using an instance variable (e.g. @error_message)?

Effectively not much difference since both values are gone after the request completes.  I think it's more of a convenience so that your view code can check one place for error messages instead of having to check both the `flash` and an instance variable.

> On a related note, how does flash work when you have multiple servers running, and thus there's a probability that the subsequent request will be executed by a different server?

The `flash` lives in the session, which is typically persisted to a database.  So if you have multiple instances of your Rails app running and they are using the same database, they have shared access to the `flash` object.  It's therefore not a problem at all if Server A writes to the `flash` object and Server B reads it out on the next request.